# Use json url in java android in the background and react to change the value

Tags: java, android, json, background, telegram

**Hi**

How can I use a url json so that I can react in the context of the program if I change the value of a key and do what I command, like the api telegram,

the `getupdates` method,
 if the text key is changed, 
the "Hi" command "To send him

**Please answer because most of this problem**

Comment: Can you explain your usecase? I don't know what are you asking.

Comment: I want to learn how to build a robot on Android

Comment: I think you can learn API methods with this app first https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaBbT.jpg